# Writing into a TCP stream in a thread, based on a condition from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I have two threads, the first one reads from the stream and the second one writes into the stream.
I also have a variable called "flag" (default to false) at the upper level out of both threads. The "read" thread modifies this flag to true when a certain condition is met. Based on the flag, if it is true, the write thread writes something into the stream.

As soon as I write into the stream, I change the flag to its original value - false, which I do inside the same write thread, if statement.

Now here is a puzzle:
I enter into the if statement if the flag is true, and I change the flag's value to false inside the if statement. However, the "write" statement inside if is never executed. It looks like when the if statement is evaluating the flag to be true or false, it is already changed to false within the if statement. Why and how is this possible. If I comment out the line inside the if statement, where the flag is changed to false, then all works fine. I need to change the flag value to false AFTER writing into the stream.

```
public static bool flag = false;

Thread readThread = new Thread(...
  // the flag is changed to true inside this thread

Thread writeThread = new Thread(() =>
{
  using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
      while (true) 
      { 
        if (flag == true) // flag should be true here, but it seems it is changed to false                         
        {
          var text = "Text to be written";
          writer.WriteLine(text );

          writer.Flush();
          flag = false; // flag is changed to false here, if I take out this line, the write statement is executed, otherwise, no
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This sounds fishy - but your code is fundamentally flawed in terms of the cross-threading... with no other synchronization, there's no guarantee that a write from one thread will be visible in another. It's hard to know whether that's what you're actually seeing happen, but if you enter the `if` statement body, it definitely *will* call `writer.WriteLine`. If you could provide a [mcve], that would make it much easier to help you and work out what's actually going on.

Comment: Uh oh, that's a spin-wait there ... bad idea. Don't you experience high CPU load?

Comment: You really, really want to have a look at synchronization primitives. A wait handle or a semaphore would go a long way.

Comment: ^^ Or maybe as easy as a (concurrent) blocking queue if this is some kind of producer/consumer scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The threads want to be independent by design, they don't have to talk to each other or be synchronized or be aware of each other. One thread is constantly reading from the stream and occasionally entering some data into a pool of data (in our simplified case, it's a basic flag variable). The other thread is periodically querying the pool and processing the data in it. The issue that I saw was strange, the variable value is being changed inside the if statement, but the change seems affecting the if statement itself, I mean the condition.